# Jquery Adding cart products - ideasoft

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I want to add cart products, the header part grows downward.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a89e.jpg)

**My homepage template:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>(%Title%)</title>
<link href="{{ themeAsset('theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1080">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ themeAsset('js/smart.drop.down.menu.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ themeAsset('js/smart.drop.down.menu.image.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="ClosePageOver();">

</div>
</noscript>
<div id="PageOver" style="z-index:998; visibility:hidden;"></div>
 <div id="header">
  <div class="headerTop">
   <div class="wrapperHtmlElementCenter">
<!-- GTranslate: https://gtranslate.io/ -->
<a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|en');return false;" title="English" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-0px -0px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="English" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|fr');return false;" title="French" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-200px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="French" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|de');return false;" title="German" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-300px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="German" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|it');return false;" title="Italian" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-600px -100px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="Italian" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|pt');return false;" title="Portuguese" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-300px -200px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="Portuguese" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|ru');return false;" title="Russian" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-500px -200px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="Russian" /></a><a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('tr|es');return false;" title="Spanish" class="gflag nturl" style="background-position:-600px -200px;"><img src="//gtranslate.net/flags/blank.png" height="24" width="24" alt="Spanish" /></a>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
a.gflag {vertical-align:middle;font-size:24px;padding:1px 0;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/24.png);}
a.gflag img {border:0;}
a.gflag:hover {background-image:url(//gtranslate.net/flags/24a.png);}
#goog-gt-tt {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-menu-value:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
body {top:0 !important;}
#google_translate_element2 {display:none!important;}
-->
</style>

 <select onchange="doGTranslate(this);"><option value="">Select Language</option><option value="tr|af">Afrikaans</option><option value="tr|sq">Albanian</option><option value="tr|ar">Arabic</option><option value="tr|hy">Armenian</option><option value="tr|az">Azerbaijani</option><option value="tr|eu">Basque</option><option value="tr|be">Belarusian</option><option value="tr|bg">Bulgarian</option><option value="tr|ca">Catalan</option><option value="tr|zh-CN">Chinese (Simplified)</option><option value="tr|zh-TW">Chinese (Traditional)</option><option value="tr|hr">Croatian</option><option value="tr|cs">Czech</option><option value="tr|da">Danish</option><option value="tr|nl">Dutch</option><option value="tr|en">English</option><option value="tr|et">Estonian</option><option value="tr|tl">Filipino</option><option value="tr|fi">Finnish</option><option value="tr|fr">French</option><option value="tr|gl">Galician</option><option value="tr|ka">Georgian</option><option value="tr|de">German</option><option value="tr|el">Greek</option><option value="tr|ht">Haitian Creole</option><option value="tr|iw">Hebrew</option><option value="tr|hi">Hindi</option><option value="tr|hu">Hungarian</option><option value="tr|is">Icelandic</option><option value="tr|id">Indonesian</option><option value="tr|ga">Irish</option><option value="tr|it">Italian</option><option value="tr|ja">Japanese</option><option value="tr|ko">Korean</option><option value="tr|lv">Latvian</option><option value="tr|lt">Lithuanian</option><option value="tr|mk">Macedonian</option><option value="tr|ms">Malay</option><option value="tr|mt">Maltese</option><option value="tr|no">Norwegian</option><option value="tr|fa">Persian</option><option value="tr|pl">Polish</option><option value="tr|pt">Portuguese</option><option value="tr|ro">Romanian</option><option value="tr|ru">Russian</option><option value="tr|sr">Serbian</option><option value="tr|sk">Slovak</option><option value="tr|sl">Slovenian</option><option value="tr|es">Spanish</option><option value="tr|sw">Swahili</option><option value="tr|sv">Swedish</option><option value="tr|th">Thai</option><option value="tr|tr">Turkish</option><option value="tr|uk">Ukrainian</option><option value="tr|ur">Urdu</option><option value="tr|vi">Vietnamese</option><option value="tr|cy">Welsh</option><option value="tr|yi">Yiddish</option></select><div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'tr',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
/* ]]> */
</script>
    <div class="userMenu _clearfix _floatRight">
     [NewUserLogin]
     [NotLoggedIn]
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="/index.php?do=members/login">Üye Girişi</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="https://www.siteadi.com.tr/index.php?do=member/signup">Yeni Üyelik</a>
       </li>
       [FbLogin]
        <li>
         <a href="javascript:fblogin();" class="facebookLogin">Facebook ile Bağlan!</a>
        </li>
       [/FbLogin]
      </ul>
     [/NotLoggedIn]
     [LoggedIn]
      <ul>
       <li>
        <span>(%MemberName%)</span>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="/index.php?do=members/myAccount">Hesabım</a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="/index.php?do=members/exec&amp;ref=logout">Çıkış</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     [/LoggedIn]
     [/NewUserLogin]
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerMiddle">
   <div class="wrapperHtmlElementCenter _clearfix">
    <div class="headerMiddleLeft _textAlignCenter _floatLeft">
     <div class="verticalCenter">
      <div class="logo">
       [HeaderLeftImage]
        <a href="/" title="(%HomeTitle%)"><img src=/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/logo222.gif border=0><!--<img src="{header_left_logo_path}" alt="(%HomeTitle%)" />--></a>
       [/HeaderLeftImage]
       [HeaderLeftSwf]
        <object>
         <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
         <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
         <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
         <param name="movie" value="{header_left_logo_path}" />
         <embed src="{header_left_logo_path}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
          allowscriptaccess="always" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true">
         </embed>
        </object>
       [/HeaderLeftSwf]
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headerMiddleRight _floatLeft">
     <div class="headerMiddleRightTop">
      <img src="/class/INNOVAEditor/assets/kredi-kart-taksit-logolar.png" style="margin-top:6px" />
     </div>

     <div class="headerMiddleRightMiddle">
<div class="cartAmount _floatRight">
       
       <div class="cartAmountButton"><a href="/index.php?do=catalog/order" class="cartAmountIcon"></a>
        <div class="_floatLeft">
         (%ShoppingCart%) Ürün
        </div>
        <div class="_floatRight">
         <a href="/index.php?do=catalog/order">Sepete Git</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="search _floatRight">
       <form name="QuickSearchFrom" action="/index.php?do=catalog/exec&ref=search" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="QuickSearch" value="1">
        <input type="text" class="searchInputClass QuickSearchBar" name="label" onblur="if(this.value.length==0){this.value='Site içi ürün arama...'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Site içi ürün arama...'){this.value=''}" value="Site içi ürün arama..." />
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="searchButton" value="" />
       </form>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="headerMiddleRightBottom _clearfix">
     
      <div class="defaultMenu _floatRight">
       <ul>
        <li>
         <a href="/">Anasayfa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="/index.php?do=catalog/newProducts">Yeniler</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="/index.php?do=catalog/rebateProducts">İndirimdekiler</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="/index.php?do=catalog/featuredProducts">Sponsor Ürünler</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="/index.php?do=static/contactus">İletişim</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="headerBottom">
   <div class="wrapperHtmlElementCenter">
    <div class="_clearfix">
     <div class="navigation _floatLeft">
      <a class="homeLink" href="/"></a>
      {%SmartDropDownMenu%}
     </div>
     <div class="navigationRightSpace _floatRight"></div>
     <div class="_clear"></div>
     <div class="menuItemTemplate _clearfix _floatRight">
      [MIT1]
       [Row1]<a href="(%ItemLink%)" target="(%ItemTarget%)">(%ItemLabel%)</a>[/Row1]
      [/MIT1]
      {MIT1}
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="mainContainer" class="_autoMargin">
  <table class="wpe100 _borderNone" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td valign="top">
     <div class="leftBox">
      (%LeftBlocks%)
     </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
     <div class="subContent">
      (%Content%)
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class="s20"></div>
 <div id="footer" style="background:white;">
  <div class="footerTop">
   <div class="wrapperHtmlElementCenter">
    <div class="announcements _floatRight">
     <script type="text/javascript">
      var o_fields_New = {
       'm_yourname'  :  {'l':'Adınız','r':'true','mn':'3','mx':'40'},
       'm_email'  : {'l':'Emailiniz','r':'true','f':'email','mn':'5','mx':'60'}
      }
      var o_config_New = {'to_disable' : ['submit'],'alert' : 1}
      var mf_New = new validator('MaillistForm_New', o_fields_New, o_config_New);
     </script>
     <form id="MaillistForm_New" action="#" onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
      <input type='hidden' name="m_yourname" id="m_yourname" value="Ziyaretci"> <!-- Value degeri, "Isim" olarak kaydedilir -->
      <input class="announcementsInput" type="text" id="m_email" name="m_email" onblur="if(this.value.length==0){this.value='E-mailinizi yazınız'}" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mailinizi yazınız'){this.value=''}" value="E-mailinizi yazınız" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="announcementsButton announcementsResetButton" onclick="javascript:if(!mf_New.exec()) return false;alert (Add2Maillist($('MaillistForm_New').serialize(),'type=r,method=post')); document.location.reload(true);" value="" /> 
     </form>
    </div>
    <div class="_clear"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footerMiddle">
   <div class="wrapperHtmlElementCenter">
    (%Footer%)
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footerBottom">
   <div class="wrapperHtmlElementCenter">
            <div style="float:right; padding-top:8px;">
            </div>
            </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<style>#IdeaSoft {background: white;}</style>

</body>
</html>
```

You can check the error:
Press the yellow button.
http://www.polattibbitekstil.com.tr/Otel-Nevresim-Takimi-Tek-Kisilik-57-Tel,PR-2.html

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this css to #PageOver and your issues will not be longer

```
#PageOver {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
.ContentDialog {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. How can I fix a small question if there is a gap in it?
picture:
http://i67.tinypic.com/j6savk.jpg

Comment: which gap you are talking about?

Comment: updated answer, add mentioned css for ".ContentDialog"

Comment: what should I do with this link : cssdeck.com/labs/e9wxosdv ?

Comment: .ContentDialog {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
}

It was perfect.

Comment: Yes, It's resolved I guess
https://s16.postimg.org/56xc4hjo5/Capture.png